# Access a printer through a virtualized XP instance running in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, printer

I have a printer which is incompatible with Ubuntu but works fine with XP. If i have XP running inside ubuntu with VirtualBox or some virtualisation solution will i be able to use my printer through xp?

Thanks for any help

Comment: My guessing is that if you connect the printer through USB and then share that into the VM it *should* work. However that doesn't help you using it over Ubuntu yet.

Comment: You must really like your printer. With the current prices it might not even be the (time) effort to do it this way, just buy a linux-compatible printer instead. As a side effect, you do not need to start your VirtualBox to print.

Comment: thanks for the replys - if it did work in the xp VM then i image there is some way to easily share files between ubuntu and the vm instance, which would make it easy to print stuff, guess buying a new printer would be easier, but i dont have much money!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  make sure you can connect and print from within your VirtualBox-XP machine.

After that, right click on the printer and select sharing and adjust your settings.

From your ubuntu system, you should be able to connect to this printer.

You can test it first by sharing a random folder on your XP box and try to access it via samba on your ubuntu system. In that way, you made sure you can also see the printer from ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Well Yes u can one way is connecting the WinXP Box to the same local network as the host
make the printer a shred printer then it will be available for your linux as well 
[HEREs](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-windows-shared-printer-ubuntu) a way on accessing a shared windows printer from linux